# Why isn't face-remapping-alist permanent-local by default?

Tags: faces, variables, buffer-local

text-scale-mode uses a buffer-local `face-remapping-alist` to scale the buffer's text, adding values like `(:height 1.2)`. It stores a "cookie" with the scaling it has applied in another local variable, `text-scale-mode-remapping`, and uses this to locate and remove previous scalings whenever the height needs to be reset.

Neither `face-remapping-alist` nor `text-scale-mode-remapping` are marked as permanent-local, so any event that wipes out buffer-local variables (e.g. changing major-modes) will clear them both. From text-scale-mode's perspective, this is fine: clearing `face-remapping-alist` causes the height to be reset, so there's no need to preserve `text-scale-mode-remapping`.

I'm using `face-remapping-alist` to change the background color of certain buffers, and want this to persist even when buffer-local variables are cleared, so I've marked it as permanent-local. This causes problems for text-scale-mode when local variables are cleared: it's height adjustments survive, but its memory of having applied them is lost when `text-scale-mode-remapping` is cleared. I can increase/decrease the height, but attempting to reset it to its true default just resets it to the height it had last time local variables were cleared.

I've fixed this by marking `text-scale-mode-remapping` permanent-local as well. I considered submitting a bug-report for text-scale-mode, but it only makes sense to mark `text-scale-mode-remapping` permanent local if `face-remapping-alist` is permanent-local too, and I don't know if that's a desireable default. I prefer it that way, but maybe there are other use-cases where it's not?

Comment: One could image a system where both the local and the global variable values were used, along the lines of hooks.

Comment: @Lindydancer: The issue is not one of global vs buffer-local, but one of buffer-local vs mode-local.  But indeed, one could imagine that `kill-all-local-variables` could be told to keep *some* of the elements of `face-remapping-alist`, like we do with `permanent-local-hook`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`permanent-local` is fundamentally a way to distinguish whether the variable's buffer-local value is really specific to this buffer or is specific to the mode currently in use in this buffer.

Sadly, in practice, for many buffer-local variables which are not specific to a particular package, whether the setting belongs to the buffer or to the mode will depend not so much on the variable itself but on the package that uses this variable.  IOW it should sometimes be `permanent-local` and sometimes not.

I suggest you report this as a bug, and take advantage of it to request another way to specify "permanent-localness".  One which can be set locally by a package and only affects this package's own use of that variable.